# How to specify discrete color of markers in Plotly.graph_objects?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, visualization, plotly.graph-objects

After a lot of searching, I still have **NOT** found how to specify discrete color mapping for markers in a scatter figure that created by plotly.**graph_objects (instead of plotly.express)**.

There are some docs about specifying discrete color mapping of plotly, but all of them are for px(plotly.express). e.g.
[Discrete colors in Python](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/).

In the fact my requirement is very simple: I have a pd.Dataframe that has a column named 'label'. It stores my category info, and may has one of three values, i.e.[0, 1, 2].

I want markers be ploted as 'red' if the column 'label' has value 2, and 'yellow' for value 1, and 'blue' for value 0.

I mimiced px's sample and coded following:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fts['label'] = make3ClassLabel( df['target'] )

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=fts['feat_x'], y=fts['feat_y0'],
                         mode='markers', marker_color=fts['label'],
            ############ following line doesn't work! #####################
                         color_discrete_sequence=['blue', 'yellow', 'red']),
            row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=fts['feat_x'], y=fts['feat_y1'],
                         mode='markers',
            ############ also doesn't work! ###############################
                         marker={ 'color':fts['label'],
                                  'color_discrete_sequence':['blue', 'yellow', 'red'] }),
            row=1, col=2)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=1, line=dict(width=0)))
fig.show()
```

Any hints or tips will be appretiated!!!

Comment: could you provide some sample data as ```marker_color``` works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create series for colors (using `map`) and then pass that series to `marker_color`:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1,2,3,4,5,2],
    "y": [2,1,3,5,4,5],
    "label": [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, -1]
})

# label: color
color_dict = {
    0: "red",
    1: "yellow",
    2: "lime"
}

# fillna is just-in-case for new/other labels
color = df["label"].map(color_dict).fillna("white")

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df["x"], 
    y=df["y"],
    mode='markers',
    marker_color=color
))

fig.update_layout(
    template="plotly_dark"
)

fig.show()
```

Is that what you need? Please leave a comment.

Comment: Yeah! It's exactly what I need!  Although it would consume more memory,  but it really works!!! I always worry about too much detail things,  maybe since that I'm used to think with c++... Thank you again!!!